# To present group of dates in read-only calendars

Tags: grails, calendar, gsp

I'm working on Grails project and i need to display group of dates in read-only calendars in my gsp.

The dates extends along 6 months and i need to present them by monthly calendar so i need 6 calendars to put my data into.

any suggestion please ? ( preferably apart from jQuery datePicker )

My data is sent from jQuery getJSON function if it does make any difference!

and here is its **code**:

```
$.getJSON("${g.createLink(action:'getTimesAsJSON')}",{id:courseId}, function(data){
    $("#selector_forCalendars").show().html(data.times) // pseudo
});
```

Comment: Have you looked at using fullcalendar? http://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: using non-existing plugin in the project is not a possible for me unfortunately!

Comment: ... but there is a plugin for it: https://grails.org/plugin/full-calendar

Answer (score 0):

Try [Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/). I found it after jQuery datePicker (it did not works for me too). Very easy, nice docs. Tell us later what you think, or ask more about it here.

**EDIT:** as someone said above, FullCalendar could be a great option too.